# Could not launch AUT using RCPTT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I am trying to record from an eclipse based UI application but whenever I try to launch the AUT from RCPTT I get the following error

> Could not launch the product because the associated workspace (aut-xxxxxxxx) is currently in use by another Eclipse Application

and keeps the Progress monitor running Untill I manually cancel the window.

I tried removing the `.lock` file from `.metadata` even then I am not able to launch the AUT from RCP Testing tool

Please provide a solution to overcome this issue

I am using *RCP Testing Tool IDE Version*: **2.4.0**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `.lock` file is the wrong approach. It is there because an RCP application is indeed using the workspace your app's launch config is pointing to.

-make sure the launch config's Workspace Data Location is pointing to a separate folder; it is not only '${workspace_loc}'

-make sure no other frozen or paused instances are locking the workspace. Check it in Debug view or even in your OS task manager